# Double tap gesture on status bar

Tags: objective-c, cydia, theos

I have made my very first app (simple re-spring) with Theos, currently it works by tapping in the icon but I wish to redo it without an icon (as a tweak) and have the phone respiring when I double tap on the task bar.

Question is: how do I add a double tap gesture on the status/task bar?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're several ways. You can use [custom events](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/intercepting-status-bar-touches-on.html) or capture touches in your app delegate class [like there](https://freshmob.com.au/how-to-capture-touches-on-the-iphone-status-bar/)

Ok, your answer is much simpler. To be useful here the `-(BOOL)scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:` method implementation for your task.

```
- (BOOL)scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
  tapIndex++; // class member
  if(tapIndex==2)
  {
    [self statusBarDoubleTapped];
    tapIndex=0;
  }
  else
  { 
    NSTimeInterval interval = 1; // one second wait for the second tap
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(interval * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           if(tapIndex==1) // one second since the only status bar tap
             tapIndex=0;
        });
  }
  return NO; // don't scroll to top
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there not an easier way? I thought I would need libstatusbar? I am very new to Objective-C and don't understand the info on that links, but are they not very very old (IOS4)?

Comment: I think there isn't easier way. Status bar is not a part of your application, and there must be some kind of API to change it's properties. Seems like libstatusbar is for visualization not a functionality customizing.

Comment: OK, thanks Astoria, so I will have to forget about this till I learn a lot more about Objective-C so I can better understand what the posts are talking about.

Comment: Thanks again Astoria, I will try this.

Answer (score 2):

I found this code, what file in my theos app would this go into?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// required
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0.0f,1.0f);
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0f,1.0f) animated:NO];
// optional
scrollView.scrollsToTop = YES; // default is YES.
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
}

- (BOOL)scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
NSLog(@"Detect status bar is touched.");
/* Your own code. */
return NO;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. That's the answer, found this just now. You should mark my answer as incorrect.

Comment: Sorry again to bother you! Does this go in the RootViewController.mm file? I get error trying to make package: "property implementation must have its
      declaration in interface 'testappApplication" And where do i add the "system("killall -9 SpringBoard");" code in this? Thanks you so much for your help.

Comment: Yes, this goes to your view controller class implementation. Unfortunately cannot find why you receive this message. You shouldn't use .mm extension (besides if you use c++ code inside) btw.

Answer (score 0):

This is complete file:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController
- (void)loadView {
self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]] autorelease];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

- (BOOL)scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    tapIndex++; // class member
    if(tapIndex==2)
    {
        [self statusBarDoubleTapped];
        tapIndex=0;

        system("killall -9 SpringBoard");
    }
    else
    {
        NSTimeInterval interval = 1; // one second wait for the second tap
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(interval * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if(tapIndex==1) // one second since the only status bar tap
                tapIndex=0;
        });
    }
    return NO; // don't scroll to top
}

//- (void)launch { system("killall -9 SpringBoard");
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did on iOS 11 using Swift 4.

```
let statusBarWindow = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBarWindow") as! UIWindow
let statusBar = statusBarWindow.subviews.first

let doubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handle(doubleTapStatusBar:)))
doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
statusBar?.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)
```